# increase size rootfs on linux (Debian)

Tags: linux

I have a linux server with a small /dev/root or rootfs partition.

It is getting full every time.

I have to remove log files from /var/log to avoid problems.

```
df -h:
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                   20G   18G  416M  98% /
/dev/root                20G   18G  416M  98% /
devtmpfs                 16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   3.2G  340K  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   6.5G     0  6.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/home  886G  224G  626G  27% /home
/dev/mapper/mail  197G   18G  170G  10% /srv/mail
/dev/mapper/web   197G  118M  187G   1% /srv/web
```

Rootfs have 18 GB used but something is strange: when I count the content of the folders together i come to 5.5 gb.

```
du -hsx * | sort -rh:
224G    home
1.6G    usr
1.2G    var
1.1G    opt
638M    lib
361M    etc
351M    root
221M    tmp
and some smaller folders.
```

I found out that I easly can increase the folder size of /dev/mapper with the code *lvresize --size +100M /dev/mapper/home* but when I try this on mij rootfs folder it says:

> Path required for Logical Volume "root"
>     Please provide a volume group name

How can I safely increase the root folder without server crash and without reinstalling?

Here my vgdisplay result:

```
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               julia
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  33
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                3
Open LV               3
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               1.80 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              471802
Alloc PE / Size       332800 / 1.27 TiB
Free  PE / Size       139002 / 542.98 GiB
VG UUID               N1WUXu-foN3-j4kE-SzRf-mdea-cAlj-NmsZ5P
```

Comment: Although this may be a good question, it's better suited for the [Super User StackExchange](https://superuser.com) because it's not directly programming related.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Llama i didn't know the difference between Super User Stack Exchange and Stackoverflow. Can i move this question to that site or do i have to repost it?

Comment: @BoPennings, you will have to repost it (You can just press edit on this question, copy all the text and then post that on SuperUser.)

Comment: Google for `Linux LVM resize volume`.  For example, you can use [lvresize](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvresize).  Here is one tutorial: [Extending a mounted Ext4 filesystem on LVM in Linux](http://www.systutorials.com/5621/extending-a-mounted-ext4-file-system-on-lvm-in-linux/)

Comment: @FoggyDay that is not working for rootfs / root. Error message: 'Path required for Logical Volume "root" Please provide a volume group name'

Comment: Use [lvdisplay](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvdisplay) to show logical volumes, [vgdisplay](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgdisplay) to show volume groups (including free space available) and [pvdisplay](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvdisplay) to show physical volumes.  For example, `lvdisplay -m julia`.  You must identify the logical volume corresponding to your rootfs.

Comment: @FoggyDay i can't find rootfs or /dev/root with the 4 commands above.

Comment: @FoggyDay it only shows /dev/julia/home and /dev/julia/mail and /dev/julia/web

Comment: Q: Does `lvdisplay -m` show any volume groups besides "julia", or logical volumes besides "home", "web" and "mail"?   STRONG SUGGESTION: Even if you find rootfs, maybe there isn't room to extend it.  Try this instead: 1) identify *which* files under /var/log are the "hogs", then 2) configure it to be a [rotating log](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/logwatch.htm): http://serverfault.com/questions/285843/is-there-a-proper-way-to-clear-logs.  See also [Creating logfile archives with logrotate](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/117/Creating_logfile_archives_with_logrotate).

Comment: @FoggyDay thanks for your response. Yesterday the server was getting full again and i had to remove files to make space. The problem was, there were no files left to delete. I recalculated the space used for every folder in the root and together it is 5gb. df -h said that 99% 19gb was used. I tried to restart the server and tried df -h again. Problem solved: it now echo's that only 5gb is used. However, I would be interested to find out how this happend.

Comment: [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is your friend.  For example, `find / -size +1048576 -print` will list all files larger than 1GB.